# What are the different patterns for S3 uRLS?

Tags: url, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In terms of s3 urls, are there really 2 kinds?  And why?  What are the different syntaxes?

```
bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key
```

and

```
s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key
```

Is this it?  Why are there 2?  Are there more?  Are these correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The additional functionality of providing multiple URL patterns for an object in the S3 is due to the Virtual Hosts and Website Hosting and publishing the data from the root directory. I got this info from

In the Bucket starting URL style - `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key` you can simple add the files like favicon, robots.txt etc where as in the other URL pattern - `s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key` - there is no notion of root directory where you can put those files.

**Content Snippet from AWS S3 Page - [Virtual Hosting of Buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html) :**

> In general, virtual hosting is the practice of serving multiple web
>   sites from a single web server. One way to differentiate sites is by
>   using the apparent host name of the request instead of just the path
>   name part of the URI. An ordinary Amazon S3 REST request specifies a
>   bucket by using the first slash-delimited component of the Request-URI
>   path. Alternatively, you can use Amazon S3 virtual hosting to address
>   a bucket in a REST API call by using the HTTP Host header. In
>   practice, Amazon S3 interprets Host as meaning that most buckets are
>   automatically accessible (for limited types of requests) at
>   http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com. Furthermore, by naming your bucket
>   after your registered domain name and by making that name a DNS alias
>   for Amazon S3, you can completely customize the URL of your Amazon S3
>   resources, for example, http://my.bucketname.com/.
>
> Besides the attractiveness of customized URLs, a second benefit of
>   virtual hosting is the ability to publish to the "root directory" of
>   your bucket's virtual server. This ability can be important because
>   many existing applications search for files in this standard location.
>   For example, favicon.ico, robots.txt, crossdomain.xml are all expected
>   to be found at the root.

Answer (score 9):

AWS is deprecating old path style URLs:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/

> Old vs. New S3 currently supports two different addressing models:
>   path-style and virtual-hosted style. Let’s take a quick look at each
>   one. The path-style model looks like either this (the global S3
>   endpoint):
>
> https://s3.amazonaws.com/jbarr-public/images/ritchie_and_thompson_pdp11.jpeg
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/jeffbarr-public/classic_amazon_door_desk.png
>
> Or this (one of the regional S3 endpoints):
>
> https://s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/jbarr-public/images/ritchie_and_thompson_pdp11.jpeg
>   https://s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/jeffbarr-public/classic_amazon_door_desk.png
>
> In this example, jbarr-public and jeffbarr-public are bucket names;
>   /images/ritchie_and_thompson_pdp11.jpeg and
>   /classic_amazon_door_desk.png are object keys.
>
> Even though the objects are owned by distinct AWS accounts and are in
>   different S3 buckets (and possibly in distinct AWS regions), both of
>   them are in the DNS subdomain s3.amazonaws.com. Hold that thought
>   while we look at the equivalent virtual-hosted style references
>   (although you might think of these as “new,” they have been around
>   since at least 2010):
>
> https://jbarr-public.s3.amazonaws.com/images/ritchie_and_thompson_pdp11.jpeg
>   https://jeffbarr-public.s3.amazonaws.com/classic_amazon_door_desk.png
>
> These URLs reference the same objects, but the objects are now in
>   distinct DNS subdomains (jbarr-public.s3.amazonaws.com and
>   jeffbarr-public.s3.amazonaws.com, respectively). The difference is
>   subtle, but very important. When you use a URL to reference an object,
>   DNS resolution is used to map the subdomain name to an IP address.
>   With the path-style model, the subdomain is always s3.amazonaws.com or
>   one of the regional endpoints; with the virtual-hosted style, the
>   subdomain is specific to the bucket. This additional degree of
>   endpoint specificity is the key that opens the door to many important
>   improvements to S3.